# 'undefined is not a function' when trying to declare new view object

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

Im working on a backbone project and im trying to declare a new view using the line:

`var tweetCompose = new ComposeTweetView();`

But i get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Im pulling in ComposeTweetView like so:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/cart/composeTweet'
], function($,_,Backbone,ComposeTweetView){
```

And the composeTweet js file looks like

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'

], function($,_,Backbone){

  var composeTweetView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#tweet-compose-popup',
    initialize: function () {

    }
  });
});
```

I havent been able to find whats wrong.

Comment: `new composeTweetView` - see lower case 'c'

Comment: shouldn't there be and return statement like: return composeTweetView in your composeTweet .js file =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return composeTweetView;` to composeTweet js after you close var `composeTweetView`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is Case-Sensitive. `composeTweetView` is not the same as `ComposeTweetView`

Comment: But on this line `], function($,_,Backbone,ComposeTweetView){, i name the parameter with a capital C